# Does $2^n\cdot \ln(1-x^n)$ converges or goes to negative infinity when $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Please show that 
$$\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}2^n\cdot \ln(1-x^n)= -\infty$$
when $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$ and 
$$\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}2^n\cdot \ln(1-x^n)$$
converges when $0<x\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Well,
$$\ln(1-x^n)=-x^n+O(x^{2n})$$
and so
$$2^n\ln(1-x^n)=-2^nx^n+O(2^nx^{2n}).$$
Will this tend to $-\infty$ for **all** $0<x<1$?

Comment: A factor $2^n$ is missing in the second equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I know I should use Taylor expansion. It turns out that I made a mistake. I have edited the question and it was perfectly solved...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use *equivalents* : if $0<x<1$,
$\;2^n\ln(1-x^n)\sim_\infty -(2x)^n.$

Answer (score 1):

Move $2^n$ into $\ln$ to get:
$$L=\ln \left(\underbrace{\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1-x^n)^{x^{-n}}}_{=e^{-1}}\right)^{x^n\cdot 2^n}=$$
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} -(2x)^n=\begin{cases} 0, \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<\frac12 \\ 
-1, \ \ \ \ \ x=\frac12 \\ 
-\infty, \ \frac12<x<\infty \end{cases}.$$